# Rotate original forge model to synchronize with other viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have loaded a model in point clound in Three js viewer and same original model in Forge. Now I want to synchronize camera but due to different coordinate system, synchrinze disturbs.

Can someone guide to set correct position/rotation of model in forge viewer with axis of rotation not disturbed?

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the more complex solution, note that Forge Viewer *does* provide a basic point cloud support, so you could potentially load your point clouds directly into Forge Viewer, together with the model. See https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo.

If you need to have two separate viewers (one for point clouds, and one for the original model) and synchronize the cameras between them, that's also possible but it'll need more work. Most importantly you'll want to find out if the point cloud data and the model use the same coordinate system, and if not, you'll need to find a transformation from one to the other. (This is not something I can answer here as I don't have any details about your files.) And finally, you can control the camera in Forge Viewer through it's APIs (for example, with [setPosition](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#setposition-pos), or [setTarget](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#settarget-target)), applying the appropriate transform if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Will look more into this.